# Azure Mobile Apps authentication - invalid format of the authentication response

Tags: c#, azure, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I'm using Azure Mobile Apps and I've set up my credentials with a Microsoft account and Facebook account.

https://studybuddy.azure-mobile.net/.auth/login/microsoftaccount/callback
https://studybuddy.azure-mobile.net/.auth/login/facebook/callback

^^ This does not return a token, I believe. "User" is never set because the "token" that I'm supposed to get back from the login doesn't exist.

Relevant code:

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> AuthenticateAsync()
    {

        string message;
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            // Change 'MobileService' to the name of your MobileServiceClient instance.
            // Sign-in using Facebook authentication.
            user = await App.MobileService
                .LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);



            message =
                string.Format("You are now signed in - {0}", user.UserId);

            success = true;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            message = "You must log in. Login Required";
        }

        var dialog = new MessageDialog(message);
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK"));
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
        return success;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that my project was migrated from Azure's old way of doing things as a Mobile Service into Azure's new Mobile Apps.

The solution is to either use the old code for an Azure Mobile Service or upgrade the project to an Azure Mobile App.